# Available Maven Profiles

Tags: maven-2, profile

Is there an easy way to figure out, preferably from the command line, what profiles are available for a particular project. I've got a big, multi-module project I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[leeand00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354081/available-maven-profiles#354360) set me on the correct path. What I was looking for is [help:all-profiles](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/all-profiles-mojo.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Look at the heading:
**How can I tell which profiles are in effect during a build?**

Another way to do it is to use grep or XPath to search for all of the  nodes.

In xpath it would be [code]\profile\id[/code]

In grep it gets a little more dicey since you have to assume that the  tag is on the line following the  tag.